# Send ephemeral response discord-button

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons

I want to send an ephemeral reply like this

[image]

with discord discord-button

**What I have tried**

```js
client.on('clickButton', async (button) => {
  if (button.id === 'openTicket') {
    await button.reply.defer();
    await button.message.channel.send('Done', {ephemeral: true});
  }
});
```

Comment: Could you maybe show us an image of you trying the command and the response please ? (also maybe switch the two lines inside the if statement ?)

Comment: If you're on v13.1.0 Have you tried `.send({content: 'Done', ephemeral: true})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't have much experience with buttons, but i recommend you to read this:
https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#deferring-and-updating-the-button-message

---

I don't think that `button.message.channel.send` could have an option for ephemeral response, since it's just sending a message to a channel, not to a specified user,
And usually ephemeral exists on "reply" since it know which user it is replying to, and so it can make it ephemeral for him only.

i'll keep you updated if i found the exact solution.

### But

For now try to do something like:

```
await button.reply({
content: 'hi',
ephemeral: true,
)
```